# How do I read a Firebase Snapshot and store a particular key-value pair in a universal array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

How do I extract the URL of every snapshot result found and append it to an array in Swift?

```
Snap (palettes) {
    "-KSoMzY6OYPyXnOPeZMb" =     {
        0 = "#000000";
        1 = "#423831";
        2 = "#2C2923";
        3 = "#424131";
        4 = "#35382A";
        URL = test;
    };
    "-KSoN-LT8I--3m-BBbfw" =     {
        0 = "#000000";
        1 = "#F6DBC5";
        2 = "#E0D6BE";
        3 = "#F6F6C5";
        4 = "#E1ECBD";
        URL = test2;
    };
```

Here's my returning JSON structure for example after calling:

```
databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: "0").queryEqual(toValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print (snapshot)
    })
```

How do I extract the URL of the multiple result snapshot and then append it to an array in Swift so the end result becomes `array = [test, test2]`?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here's my JSON tree:

```
{
  "palettes" : {
    "-KSoMzY6OYPyXnOPeZMb" : {
      "0" : "#000000",
      "1" : "#423831",
      "2" : "#2C2923",
      "3" : "#424131",
      "4" : "#35382A",
      "URL" : "test"
    },
    "-KSoN-LT8I--3m-BBbfw" : {
      "0" : "#000000",
      "1" : "#F6DBC5",
      "2" : "#E0D6BE",
      "3" : "#F6F6C5",
      "4" : "#E1ECBD",
      "URL" : "test2"
    },
    "-KSoN-e0huiOxyj0jadl" : {
      "0" : "#F1CBC1",
      "1" : "#FBE1C9",
      "2" : "#E5DCC2",
      "3" : "#FBFBC9",
      "4" : "#000000",
      "URL" : "test3"
    },
    "-KSqFcPjjtRkRDbzH-lc" : {
      "0" : "#27643A",
      "1" : "#2B6E52",
      "2" : "#000000",
      "3" : "#2B676E",
      "4" : "#274E64",
      "URL" : "test4"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your JSON tree

Comment: Done, updated my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var arrayVar = [String]()

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("palletes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                let _URL = each.value["URL"] as! String
                arrayVar.append(_URL)

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, returned with ["test3", "test2", "test", "test4"]. Now I just gotta figure out how to turn these strings into NSUrl and then into an array of images to be displayed in collectionsview.

Comment: @Dravidian   Could you please look [at my question here too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212468) Many thanks